# Does Miitomo run on Samsung phones?

Tags: android, miitomo

I'm in [Germany](https://miitomo.com/en/countries/). I have a Galaxy Note 4 and Galaxy S6. Some of the most powerful phones there are.

Yet [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zaaa) says:

> This app is incompatible with all of your devices.

What's going on? Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Can you find it in play store through the phone/tablet? The play store page says all of my devices are compatible, which includes a piece of crap Samsung Galaxy Ace II X from 2012.

Comment: No, Miitomo does not show up in search results in the Google Play app on any of my phones.

Comment: What version of Android is on your devices?

Comment: Not really relevant, since you can't even download it, but apparently [Miitomo is blocked and won't launch on rooted devices](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4cp855/psa_miitomo_blocks_root_users/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard of this issue:

The easiest workaround to solve it is to download the APK file of the game:

1. Google for Miitomo.apk (I am not lazy but not sure if its allowed to post every link here.
2. Load the *.apk file onto your phone and open it with a file manager. (If you do not have such one: "ES File Explorer" would be a famous example which is available in Play Store. If you downloaded the *.apk file directly from your phone's internet browser, you can also probably open it from the "Downloads"-App.)
3. Install the app. (If you have installed an *.apk you will probably get a warning and you will be led to your phone settings since there has to be set a checkbox in order to install apps from "Unknown Sources".)